# Diff two files in shell script

Tags: file, shell, parsing

Assume we have two files named file1 and file2.

```
File1:    
a=b    
c=d    
e=f

File2:   
a=p  
c=o  
e=f  
g=h  
i=j
```

Here file2 has the same keys of file1 and different values.Apart from some extra key-value pair of its own.

Compare two files keys, replace file2 value with file1 value based on key match. Retain the new entries in file2.

So, my final output should be :

```
File2: 
a=b  
c=d  
e=f  
g=h  
i=j
```

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Looks like this should be pretty straightforward in `awk`. We're not here to write it for you, you have to do your own work. We'll help you fix it if you can't get it working.

Comment: BTW, this is not what "diff" means. That means to report the differences between two files. You want to merge them in some way.

Comment: Explored that how to parse a properties file having a key=value pairs. But fully confused with the associative arrays. Thought better post a question.

Comment: First you should try writing code on your own if you are facing any difficulty then people can help you.

Comment: Barmar, thanks for your suggestion.I am very new to AWK and I have seen a lot of command line answers for different requirements. Didn't find any matches for my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Quickest way without using scripts is using the tool called "meld".
 I can give one way of approaching the problem (though not the best)

1.read from first file line by line

2.split based on "=" expression

3.store the two variables as key and value
 make an array of all key value pairs

4.read from the second file and repeat the procedure

compare the two arrays and save values not in first array only

In this specific case you can use "cut" command in shell to choose fields .
I personally  prefer Perl script for file operations like this :)

Comment: Thanks achoora for your reply, will try and update with proper approach for this issue.